# ArcGIS Online's new map viewer - sublayers?

Tags: layers, arcgis-online

I just opened up ArcGIS online for the first time in a few weeks and I see their new map view is out.  I'm trying to get comfortable with it, but I'm struggling to find the sublayers option for layers that have more than one sublayer.  For example, for [these LANDFIRE layers](https://landfire.cr.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Landfire/US_140/MapServer), there are multiple sublayers you can access.  With the classic map viewer, they're easy to navigate:

[image]

Under the content section you can clearly see the sublayers and toggle them on and off.

Now in the new UI:

[image]

For the life of me I don't see anywhere you can look through the different sublayers.  I must be missing something obvious here?

Comment: I wonder if map image layers aren't fully supported or if they are planned to become obsolete. If you noticed everything in the right pane other than properties is grayed out as well. I wonder if the new workflow is going to be use all individual feature layers and then group them. I hope that's not the case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the web map roadmap, it says styling and configuring of map image layers will be available later this year.

https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-documents/map-viewer-roadmap/ta-p/920839?attachment-id=62505